# Why does Date.now - a given date work? Documentation shows that Date.now() returns the ms since 1970

Tags: javascript, date

```js
const daysFromNow = (date) => Math.round((date-Date.now())/(1000*3600*24))

console.log(daysFromNow(new Date('07/04/2020'))); 

//result is -534
```

Given the above, why does it work? I've read that .now() gives back the ms since 1970. Does the passed in date hold a value of the ms since 1970 as well?

Comment: Yes, because "Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Also, it doesn't really matter which epoch the Date object uses in your question, because you're simply calculating the relative difference between two dates. Their absolute reference to time does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the passed in date hold a value of the ms since 1970 as well?

The Date object represents a specific moment on earth, so yes you can retrieve that the milliseconds since 1970 in milliseconds.

A `Date` object has a [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) function that returns the primitive value of the Date:

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

So `(new Date()).valueOf()` and `Date.now()` are equivalent:

```js
console.log((new Date()).valueOf())
console.log(Date.now())
```

And the `valueOf` is called for conversion in the case of `date - Date.now()` because `date` is a `Date` object and `Date.now()` returns a number.

Here an example of a custom object with a `valueOf` function:

```js
let test = {
  valueOf() {
    return 5;
  }
}

console.log(test - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's work because of [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) property. That property return a number, implemented in all objects in js. You can also owerride it in your objects.

Here an example of using for creating add chain js function.

```js
function add(x) {
  const fn = (y) => add(x + y);
  fn.valueOf = () => x;
  return fn;
}

const addTen = add(5)(5);

console.log(addTen + 1) // 11
```

Comment: *valueOf* doesn't always return a number, the default [*Object.prototype.valueOf*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-object.prototype.valueof) just returns the object so `obj.valueOf() === obj`. Date objects have their own [*Date.prototype.valueOf*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.valueof) that returns the *Date's* time value. ;-)